# WP Rocket cache file slow to load

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, gtmetrix

I'm trying to optimize my site and using GTMetrix to see which requests that takes a lot of time. And I can see that the heaviest file is the cache file generated in `wp-content/cache/min/1/78d81b6108cf10884c20ab592c9fbb46.js`, is that as it should be or is it too large?

[image: Load time from GTMetrix]

[image: PageSpeed says it takes 6 second to load]

Answer (score 0):

After finally working out how to type your domain name (ignorant british man that I am!) I get similar times for that script and https://xn--bstaelscootern-5hb.se/wp-content/cache/min/1/4fac67378f86d8e54c6af5529b17e3d5.css.

It is possible that the cache hadn't been fully created when you ran your test so it took longer as it was being generated 'on the fly' and some of the downloading time was actually waiting for the file to be generated.

If you install a cache plugin you still have to load the page sometimes for it to generate the cached files.

If this was the first run after enabling the plugin then it would be slow, same goes for if you made a change to the file and then ran first time as it needs to regenerate the cached version of the file.

On the runs I have done it loads in the same amount of time as similarly sized files.

Comment: Haha! I should have provided the URL... So, I've actually run the test multiple times and I get the same results, it just is that slow every time I test in on GTMetrix or Google PageSpeed. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Ah for Google PSI the problem you have is script evaluation and execution time (I didn't recognise the column headers - yet again language barrier!) So what this is showing is that you have JavaScript that is taking a long time to parse and evaluate (as PSI simulates a mobile phone CPU speed). Switch off WP rocket and run again - see if any scripts are taking a long time to evaluate, if so they need fixing. If not then check scripts for errors etc. as it could be WP rocket is doing something to try to correct a parse error (I noticed about 50 commas in the script  one after the other)